# Reading a range of data from Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am quite new to using `C#` for reading Excel data. I am using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to read an excel sheet data. But my problem is the sheet starts from the cell `B4` (instead of usual `A1`) and hence I am facing difficulties while reading the data. Following is my method:

```
   public static DataSet GetExcelFileData(String fileNameWPath, String sheetName, String rangeName, String fieldList, String whereClause)
    {
        DataSet xlsDS = new DataSet();
        String xlsFields = String.Empty;
        String xlsWhereClause = String.Empty;
        String xlsSqlString = String.Empty;
        String xlsTempPath = @"C:\temp\";
        //Copy File to temp folder locations....
        String xlsTempName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNameWPath);
        xlsTempName = xlsTempName.Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace(" ", "_").Replace("-", "_").Replace("&", String.Empty).Replace("~", String.Empty) + ".xls";
        //Check if sqlFields and Where Clause is Empty....
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldList))
            xlsFields = "*";
        else
            xlsFields = fieldList;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(whereClause))
            xlsWhereClause = whereClause;


        //String oleDBConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source ={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; IMEX=1\"", xlsTempPath + Path.GetFileName(xlsTempName));
        String oleDBConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=0\"", xlsTempPath + Path.GetFileName(xlsTempName));

        OleDbConnection xlsConnect = null;
        try
        {
            File.Copy(fileNameWPath, xlsTempPath + Path.GetFileName(xlsTempName), true);
            xlsConnect = new OleDbConnection(oleDBConnString);
            OpenConnection(xlsConnect);

            //Get Worksheet information 
            DataTable dbSchema = xlsConnect.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            if (dbSchema == null || dbSchema.Rows.Count < 1)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to get worksheet information for {0}", fileNameWPath));
            }

            DataRow[] sheets = dbSchema.Select(String.Format("TABLE_NAME LIKE '*{0}*'", sheetName.Replace("*", String.Empty)));

            if (sheets.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Could not find worksheet {0} in {1}", sheetName, fileNameWPath));
            }
            else
            {
                string realSheetName = sheets[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                //Build Sql String
                xlsSqlString = String.Format("Select {0} FROM [{1}${2}] {3}", xlsFields, sheetName, rangeName, xlsWhereClause);
                //xlsSqlString = String.Format("Select {0} FROM [{1}${2}] {3}", xlsFields, sheetName, "", xlsWhereClause);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(xlsSqlString, xlsConnect);
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(xlsSqlString, xlsConnect);
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                adapter.Fill(xlsDS);
                return xlsDS;

            }


        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            if (ex2.Message.ToLower().Equals("no value given for one or more required parameters."))
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Error in Reading File: {0}. \n Please Check if file contains fields you request Field List: {1}", fileNameWPath, xlsFields));
            }
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Error in Reading File: {0}\n Error Message: {1}", fileNameWPath, ex2.Message + ex2.StackTrace));
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection(xlsConnect);
            File.Delete(xlsTempPath + Path.GetFileName(xlsTempName));
        }
    }
```

Also, I have tried using the older veriosn of Jet Engine: Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and it works fine. But since we have migrated to 64 bit server, we must use the latest OleDb 12.0 engine. Everytime I specify a range ("B4:IV65536") and try to read data, I get the following exception:

"The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Report1$B4:IV65536'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."

Also, please note that I have tried many permutations-combinations of HDR, IMEX (setting them to Yes/No & 0/1 respectively but that hasn't helped).

Please suggest me a workaround.

Thanks,
Abhinav